# Can a class with this vector member be initialised using the implicit constructor?

Tags: c++, constructor, stdvector

My class needs a member `std::vector<MyType> my_list` with five elements. The `MyType`s should be initialised with their default constructor. Will I have to write an explicit constructor for this class, or can it be solved without?

Answer (score 2):

In C++11 you can do the following and get the vector properly initialized by the implicitly generated constructor:

```
class foo {
    std::vector<int> my_list { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
};
```

Without C++11, you have to write it yourself:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
T* begin(T(&arr)[N]) { return &arr[0]; }

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
T* end(T(&arr)[N]) { return &arr[0] + N; }

class foo {
    // imitate initializer list
    static const int default_list[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    std::vector<int> my_list;
public:
    foo() : my_list(begin(default_list), end(default_list)) {}
};
```

Comment: Isn't that an explicit constructor? `foo() : ...`

Comment: @Andreas In a sense, yes (it doesn't have the `explicit` keyword though, so in strict C++ parlance, it's an implicit ctor). There's no other option in C++03.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to write your own. The compiler generated constructor will default initialize `my_list`, which means it'll be empty. You need something like this:

```
class MyClass {
    std::vector<MyType> my_list;

    MyClass() : my_list(5) {}
};
```